# Двухсторонняя сортировка выбором Double selection sort

Tags: c#, сортировка

У кого либо может быть есть работающий код на C# (простыми конструкциями сделанный) с двухсторонней сортировкой выбором (Double selection sort)?
Можете пожалуйста поделится?

ссылка поясняющая метод двухсторонней сортировки выбором

http://algolab.valemak.com/selection-double

Comment: А односторонняя реализация у Вас есть? Вот и добавьте туда по аналогии с выбором минимума ещё и максимум, и в конце прохода обмен с последним элементом. Нужно только следить, чтобы конфликтов не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот пример:

```
        int []arr = {10,32,1,16,49,50,4,7,25,39,11,1,55,50};
        int minindex=0, maxindex=0;
        for (int j = 0; j <  arr.Length/2; j++)
        {
            var min = int.MaxValue;var max = 0;
            var tmp=0;
            for (int i = j; i < arr.Length-j; i++)
            {
                if (min > arr[i])
                {
                    min = arr[i];
                    minindex = i;                      
                }
                if (arr[i] > max)
                {
                    max = arr[i];
                    maxindex = i;                       
                }   
            }

            tmp = arr[j];
            if (j == maxindex)
            {
                maxindex = minindex;
            }

            arr[j] = min;
            arr[minindex] = tmp;

            tmp = arr[arr.Length - j - 1];
            arr[arr.Length - j - 1] = max;
            arr[maxindex] = tmp;                  
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам! Лучи благодарности!